# webserver forcing browser to only open one parallel connection

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Hello I'm trying to write a webserver in C#.
The server is going to dynamically create a website based on some templates I defined.

The problem I have is that you only can access the webpage if you enter a password.
So I decided to make the browser open up a keep-alive connection, passing every request through it.
Then I have control over logged in clients and not logged in clients. Now the problem is that Firefox and Google Chrome, when it comes to requesting the images on the website, they just open up another connection from the same ip but a different port. 
My webserver thinks that its another client and sends the login http page instead of the requested image. 
So every time the website loads only 1 - 4 images are getting actually sent.

Now my question: Is there any way to force the browser **NOT** to open up parallel connections?

Or if not possible how should I deal with the problem?

For those who like to see some code here is what the core of the server looks like, just to understand my problem:

```
void ThreadStart()
{
    while (true)
    {
        RunClient(listener.AcceptTcpClient());
    }
}
void RunClient(TcpClient c)
{
        Thread tht = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(RunIt));
        tht.IsBackground = true;
        tht.Start(c);//The login page is getting sent...
        thtt.Add(tht);
}
```

Thanks in advance, Alex

Comment: 1) Please don't prefix your titles with strings like "C#". That's what we have tags for here on [SO]. 2) You'd do better to read the [faq] and learn how to do formatting here, rather than using HTML.

Comment: Couldn't you just give me a constructive hint instead of criticizing my formatting?

Comment: Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel? Even if you decided using ASP.NET isn't the right choice for you, at least use authentication using cookies or session identifier. There is a reason everybody else does that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Authenticating a HTTP connection rather than individual requests is wrong, wrong, wrong. Even if you could make the browser reuse a single connection (which you can't, because that's not how HTTP works), you wouldn't be able to count on this being respected by proxies or transparent web caches.

This is (some of) what cookies were invented for. Use them, or some kind of session identifier built into the URLs.

Comment: I thought of that already but cookies are a very bad idea because of the connection being established over http. Only the login process goes over https. Wouldn't that make session hijacking very easy?

Comment: What, if you're authenticating over https (which is good), how were you going to associate a plain http connection (which will be a separate TCP connection) with an earlier https login transaction anyway? Why not do everything (or at least everything that must be authenticated or kept secret) over https?

Comment: Well, first a HTTPS connection is established and then after POSTing the password over https, my listener already expects the same IP and PORT connecting again, now it starts a HTTP connection sending the header "Connection: Keep-alive". From that point the connection may not be closed without having to re-login!

Comment: That won't work. You have no right to expect that the client will reuse the same port for an outgoing connection. Usually the TCP driver in the OS will select local port numbers for outgoing connections randomly each time one is made. The program doing the connection can override this, but it takes special effort to do so, and browsers have absolutely no reason to do that.

Comment: OH well I didnt know that. I just tested it using localhost:23456 in my browser...
So are you telling me that it wont work and that my concept is bad and that I should throw everything away I worked on the past 2 days?

Comment: Yes. It may have worked for you (sort of) in a single test, but there's no way it's going to be dependable in the wild.

Comment: OK I'm going to rethink my strategy. Looks like I have to come up with a new design for the webserver...